# reverse engineering prevention for manifest file

Tags: android, decompiling, android-proguard, android-security

I have used Proguard rules to prevent reverse engineering in my app.
Now I want to restrict the attacker from decompiling the manifest file with IOException and any exception when the app is decompiled.

Please help me out.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267981/should-i-spend-time-preventing-piracy-of-my-app

Comment: Currently its not possible as per my knowledge. You can avoid using API keys there, use string file to store API keys.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prevent a determined reverse engineer, on ay platform.  Your best defense is simply this-  your app just isn't valuable enough to do it to.  There's nothing in it that couldn't be written from scratch quicker than reverse engineering it.  Practice good data security and stop worrying about it.

Comment: if you decompile any banking app, the app gets decompiled but when you try to open manifest file It will show IOException and you won't be able to see the code, event the obfuscated code